# Following Excel precedents to cells on other sheets

Tags: microsoft-excel

Let's say I have a cell that references another cell, on a different sheet. For example, cell A2 (of Sheet1) below.

[image]

When I press the extremely useful Trace Precedents button, it draws arrows from the cells being referenced by the formula in the selected cell.

[image]

As you can see, for the off-sheet reference, it shows a little icon off to the side (in cell C3 here—but C3 is completely uninvolved), and draws an arrow from there.

I want to **go to** the off-sheet cell, in this case Sheet2!A1. I've tried right-clicking on the little icon and other natural actions, to no avail. Surely there is a way?

Answer (score 26, accepted):

Try double-click on the dotted line - that should bring up a Goto box.

Answer (score 0):

To find various instances that a cell value (say sheet "sheet1", cell "T10") is used in all other sheets of the same workbook, use ctrl-F to bring up a "Find, replace" window.  In 'Find what' and enter the location info of the cell, i.e. 'sheet1'!T10.  Make sure "Within:" is set to "workbook".  Click "Find All" and you will see a list that you can sort through to see where and how the cell is used.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).